# How to switch Heroku Connect from sandbox to production?

Tags: salesforce, heroku-postgres, heroku-connect

Preparing for a large Salesforce migration, I need to switch an existing Heroku Connect instance from sandbox to production.  It appears this isn’t possible, even with admin privileges across the board. Heroku docs don’t appear to mention this scenario.   What am I missing, or how is this achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In three steps:

1. Export object/field mappings from the existing Connect instance
2. Create a separate Connect instance, authorizing to the production Salesforce org
3. Import the object/field mappings into new Connect instance

This assumes the two Salesforce orgs have the same object/field definitions.